# LiveBindings connection between TScrollbar.Position and TCheckBox.Left?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe4, livebindings

In the Delphi XE4 LiveBindings Designer, why I cannot connect a TScrollBar Position property to a TCheckBox Left property? So when I move the scrollbar thumb at runtime this should change the horizontal position of the checkbox.
In the image below you can see that when the Scrollbar1 Position property field is selected (blue), the Checkbox1 Left property field is not green; which indicates that the two fields cannot be connected:

[image: Visual LiveBindings]

Since both TScrollbar.Position and TCheckBox.Left properties are Integer type, I don't understand why they cannot be connected.
However, the CheckedState property field is colored green, which seems strange, since CheckedState is a Boolean type.

Comment: I added the delphi tag. You must always include it in a delphi specific question.

Comment: Why don't you simply use the ScrollBar OnChange event with one line of code : `CheckBox1.Left := ScrollBar1.Position;`

Comment: Yes, I could do this, as many LiveBindings could be replaced this way. However, the question is: "Why I cannot connect a TScrollBar Position property to a TCheckBox Left property?", and I forward this question to you.

Comment: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE4/en/LiveBindings_in_RAD_Studio may give you some indication as to what LiveBindings was conceptually intended for.